# GAS Youtube Data Api アクセスの禁止

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api, youtube

こんにちは。
GoogleAppsScriptのYoutubeDataApiのエラーについてお聞きしたいことがあります。
私はGASでスプレッドシートにある動画のリンクをYoutubeの再生リストに追加するプログラムを書いていて、
そのプログラムを走らせたときにこのようなエラーが出ました。

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.playlistItems.list failed with error: Access Forbidden. The authenticated user cannot access this service.
```

このエラーが出る前までは正常に追加処理が出来ていたのですが、
ある日突然実行時にこのようエラーが出るようになってしまいました。

```
GoogleJsonResponseException：youtube.playlistItems.listへのAPI呼び出しが次のエラーで失敗しました：アクセスが禁止されています。 認証されたユーザーはこのサービスにアクセスできません。
```

直訳するとこのような内容になりますが、認証は初回実行時にやったつもりでいて、
一度Youtube Data Apiのサービスを消してから入れ直したのですがそれでも上のようなエラーが出てしまい、
正常にプログラムの実行をすることが出来ませんでした。

## お聞きしたいこと

- このエラーが出てしまう理由
- このエラーの解決方法

## 唯一思い当たること

- 学校から配られたGoogle Workspaceアカウントを利用していること

以上です。
詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

Google Workspace では YouTube へのアクセスを管理者が制限できるようなので、こちらが影響している可能性があります。

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6212415?hl=ja